# Vector geometry problem

Tags: calculus, geometry, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

A quadrangular pyramid OABCD with square ABCD as the bottom. OA = 1, AB = 2, BC = 2 Also, OA perpendicular to AB, OA perpendicular to AD. 
Question 1 : Find the inner product $\overrightarrow {OA}.\overrightarrow {OB}$ and the size of the cross product |$\overrightarrow {OA}X\overrightarrow {OB}$ |
I got this the inner product is OA.OB=1 
2. Let E denote the point dividing the OD  into 2: 3, and let F be the midpoint of OC. **Also A plane including three points A, E, and F and a point intersecting the side OB or its extension are defined as G**. At this time, express OG with OA,OB,and OC . can someone give me hint? thanks

I dont understand where is G in the plane and what is the relation with A,E,F? 
And why $\overrightarrow {AG}= s. \overrightarrow {AE}+t. \overrightarrow {AF}$ ??

Comment: The highlighted sentence is indeed obscure. I think $G$ is simply the intersection between plane $AEF$ and line $OB$.

Comment: @aretino yes but is it possibly to draw the intersection point ? AEF and line OB are in the same plane right?

Comment: Line $OB$ is not on plane $AEF$. Just make a sketch to get convinced.

Comment: @aretino yes thats why it is linearly dependent? so it can be represented by combination linear? with AG is point outside of the plane AEF but the origin must be the same?

Comment: There must be a typo in your last equation: it doesn't make sense as written.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a diagram made with GeoGebra:

[image]

Comment: thankyou!!!! thats so cool!! i dont know there is an app like this hahaha, thankyou so much for the drawing too!!!!. i edited my last equation, sorry for typo!!